# Zabbix trigger expression

Tags: triggers, expression, zabbix

I have one item with the two possible value of a string.

OK and ERROR,

I need trigger expression with will switch trigger to Problem only when 20 last value is 'ERROR' and will switch to OK only when all 20 last value will be OK.

I was testing with {iteam.count(120,error,"like")}>1
or with regexp but it return 1 at each change occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem only when last 20 values is 'ERROR':

```
{item.count(#20,error,"like")}>19
```

Trigger version with hysteresis (switch to OK only when last 20 values will be OK) is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Reference: http://blog.zabbix.com/no-more-flapping-define-triggers-the-smart-way/1488/